# Debugging Word 2010 Add-in with an existing document instead of a new one

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, add-in

I'm not sure if this is a dumb question because Google doesn't show anything related to it. Basically, I'm creating a Word 2010 Add-in in Visual Studio 2010 and during debugging I want to use an existing document to run the code on, but by default it creates a new blank document when I debug. How can I run the code on an existing document?